# how to change the button colour if checkbox is checked in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a agree button below two checkbox. i want to enable the agree button and also change the colour of agree button after both checkbox is checked. i have used custom images for checkbox.
    i am using this code

This is my UIButton class

```
let selectedImage = UIImage(named: "checkbox_checked")
let unselectedImage = UIImage(named: "checkbox_unchecked")


class Qbutton: UIButton {

    //Bool Property
    var isChecked:Bool = false{
        didSet{
            if isChecked {
                self.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
    }
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if(sender == self){
            if isChecked == true{
                isChecked = false
                print("true")
                self.setImage(unselectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            }else{
                isChecked = true
                print("false")
                self.setImage(selectedImage, forState: UIControlState.Selected)

            }
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(isChecked, forKey: "isBtnChecked")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
    }

}
```

AND THIS IS MY VIEW CONTROLLER CLASS WHERE I AM USING QBUTTON CLASS

```
checkBoxOne = Qbutton(frame: CGRectMake(X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT))
        isChecked = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked")
        checkBoxOne.isChecked = isChecked
        self.view.addSubview(checkBoxOne)

checkBoxTwo = Qbutton(frame: CGRectMake(X,Y,WIDTH,HEIGHT))
        checkBoxTwo.isChecked = isChecked
        self.view.addSubview(checkBoxTwo)
```

NOW I WANT TO CHANGE THE COLOR OF AGREE BUTTON IF USER CHECK BOTH THE CHECKBOXES.

Comment: Rahul; post the code you have now! Be more specific, you can change the background, you can change the image, the text colour? One, two, ten checkboxes, should be trivial you just need to keen a track of how many have been checked. KVO would be one of several options to trigger the colour changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with your logic of the QButton. You are storing the checked state in user defaults property `isBtnChecked`. But there are multiple instances of QButton (2 checkboxes), so even one is checked the property will be set to true. Avoid storing the state of the checkbox in defaults and instead query the state from checkBoxOne and checkBoxTwo using their is `isChecked` property.

Answer (score 1):

Check if both check box button  selected is true then  update your agree botton accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If this button just contains text, you can use the code:

`button.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)`

Answer (score 0):

=> Take array for storing state of check button state. By default array contain "0" value for all elements , means if you have 5 checkboxes than array contain [@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0"] . now whenever button press , alter the state of button in array. so that if 2nd button pressed , and i have "0" state for that button than i replace "0" with "1" and check if array contain all "1" value than change the colour of agree button.

=> comment below if not understand any thing what i said.